# detect a range with cvThreshold

Tags: opencv

based on [this article](http://www.matmidia.mat.puc-rio.br/sibgrapi2009/media/posters/59928.pdf) skin could be approximatly detected using hsv color space and taking hue range between 6 and 38.

i tried to use some combination of cvThreshold, in particular i thought this could be the right way:

```
cvThreshold(planeH, planeH, 38, UCHAR_MAX, CV_THRESH_TRUNC);
cvThreshold(planeH, planeH, 6, UCHAR_MAX, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

but it does not work.
some help?

Comment: could you please post some more code - since you should have some dilate and erode calls as well.

Comment: i'm interested only in understand if cvThreshold is applaid correctly to get the specified range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the function you are really after is the [cvInRange](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=inrange#void%20cvInRange%28const%20CvArr*%20src,%20const%20CvArr*%20lower,%20const%20CvArr*%20upper,%20CvArr*%20dst%29) function. This function allows you to specify multiple intervals simultaneously.

For example,

```
CvMat* skinMask = cvCreateMat(...);
cvInRange(hsvImage, CvScalar(6, loS, loV), CvScalar(38, hiS, hiV), skinMask);
```

Where `loS, loV, hiS, hiV` are the lower and upper bounds of the S and V channels respectively.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9021811/951860) is another one of my answers using `inRange`. If you can use the C++ interface, I would recommend that over the C interface as it has more features and is the actively maintained side of OpenCV going forward.

Comment: ok cool. i've read a lot of your answer about opencv, you are a master, man.

Comment: Thanks! I enjoy helping out! It's pretty cool seeing all the different ways OpenCV gets used :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you can safely use the same image (planeH) as input and output of the function. You might get border effects. Better use a temporary image

Also, if you look here : http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~bouakaz/OpenCV-0.9.5/docs/ref/OpenCVRef_ImageProcessing.htm#decl_cvThreshold you'll see that the output of cvthreshold is a binary image (either value or 0) if you're not using CV_THRESH_TOZERO. So your code is biased, as after the operation planeH should contain only two different values

What you should do is use CV_THRESH_TOZERO, or perform each operation on two different images, and then perform on OR operation on both results (the result being a binary image with 1 for pixels between 6 and 38).

Comment: Then have a llok at the documentation man http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/core_operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=or#Or. Should be your bedbook :).